# Offscreen video capture?

Tags: video, video-capture

I want to record 2 things. One is a replay/video of a game (windowed, not fullscreen) and the other is a live camera/video stream. I probably can use something to capture an rtmp which is what i think the stream is using. BUt how do i capture replays/appications?

I want to continue working on my stuff and capture the video. I know of a screen capture but the problem is i can accidentally block the video or it takes to much screen space which causes me to do less. Is there a way i can have an offscreen video buffer and use screen capture to record that data?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the "record the game" part of your problem using [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/news.php). It hooks into DirectDraw/OpenGL and it appears from their changelog that it supports games running in windowed mode. I think you should be able to run a capture that will work even if the window is blocked.

There's a free demo, which watermarks the video I believe, or you can buy fraps for $37

Comment: Sounds interesting and good. Before marking this i'll wait for other replies.